# conditionalPanel Shiny to Hide Check Box options

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to figure out how to use `conditionalPanel` in Shiny to remove options from `checkboxGroupInput` based on what is selected on the `sliderInput`.

Below is my code: 
ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
        titlePanel("XXXXX"),
        sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                        checkboxGroupInput("product.input", label = "Labels",
                                           choices=c("Product A"="P1",
                                                     "Product B"="P2",
                                                     "Product C"="P3",
                                                     "Product D"="P4",
                                                     "Product E"="P5",
                                                     "Product F"="P6"),
                                           selected=c("P1", "P2","P3","P4","P5","P6")),

                        sliderInput("prod.input", 
                                    label = "Select Month",
                                    sep="",
                                    min =1 , max = 12, value = c(5,8),step=1),
                        conditionalPanel(condition="prod.input<5",
                                         checkboxGroupInput("product.input", label = "Labels",
                                                            choices=c("Product A"="P1",
                                                                      "Product B"="P2",
                                                                      "Product E"="P5",
                                                                      "Product F"="P6")))),
        mainPanel((tabsetPanel(
                tabPanel("Table1",h2("Table Header"),tableOutput("figure"))))))))
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
        output$figure <- renderPlot({
        })
}
)
```

When the slider input is less than 5, I want the two checkboxes "Product C" and "Product D" to disappear. When I use conditionalPanel, a new list appears instead of the same list being updated. Any leads on how I can fix this  will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me like you could solve your issue by using `updateCheckboxGroupInput` (see [Shiny reference](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/updateCheckboxGroupInput.html)).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to change the checkboxGroupInput using conditionalPanel, but it's pretty simple if you use renderUI:

ui.R

```
uiOutput('product.input')
```

server.R

```
output$product.input <- renderUI({
   allchoices <- c("Product A" = "P1", "Product B" = "P2", "Product C" = "P3", 
                   "Product D" = "P4", "Product E" = "P5", "Product F" = "P6")
   if(input$prod.input[2] < 5) allchoices <- allchoices[-c(3:4)]

   checkboxGroupInput("product.input", label = "Labels", choices = allchoices, 
                      selected = allchoices)
})
```

ps.: I'm not sure, but I think that once you've stated an 'input-object' in the ui you can't really change it. If you  were to use the conditionalPanel, you'd probably have to declare two of them, each of them with one of the possible declarations of 'product.input'.